# Jquery-ui dialog box 'x' button image is not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am doing a simple jquery-ui dialog application with my js,css code as,

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="dialog">this is a dialog box</div>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    this jquery ui is added.....
    <script>     
      $("#dialog").dialog() 
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When i add a simple dialog box, the `x` mark inside the dialog's close button is not visible.

Am i missing inclusion of any image sprite file?[image]

Comment: put your code js fiddle

Comment: Have you got images?

Comment: It's better that you add the script tags in <head>.

Comment: I can see that the background gradient images are missing too. Does the folder that contains `jquery-ui.css` contains an `images` sub folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
Include "sprite image" and if you put css file in project css folder means put image in image folder and add following changes

.ui-state-default .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png");//change path of image in css(jquery-ui.css)
}
```

Comment: I utilize (CSS): button.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    background-image: ~ }

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, I think you have the bootstrap library. Some version of bootstrap and jquery-ui have conflict with the `.button()` method, and if your `bootstrap.js` is placed after `jquery-ui.js`, the bootstrap `.button()` overrides your `jquery` button and the `jquery-ui 'X'` image would then not show up.

This issue **[here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/6094)** might be helpful to know more!!

The below order works to showup your `close` button

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

The below causes issue

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

You can also run `$.fn.button.noConflict()` just before you call your dialog and everything should work fine!

Comment: Thank you - this was my issue.  Unfortunately they are included upstream and I can't correct the blunder...

Answer (score 1):

Might be you have forget to include the [sprite image](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks very much like it wasn't able to load image resources for some reasons. Try to open your browser's network console and check it for any errors.

Perhaps it's trying to load the images from css/images/* rather than from the place that you're expecting for.